# How to update 'defaults' in leaflet directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-leaflet-directive, ui-leaflet

I am using [leaflet directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-leaflet/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/custom-parameters-example).
I set defaults for map like:

```
defaults: {
                    tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    scrollWheelZoom: false
                }
```

And later I want to update `defaults` with some other event like `click`.
So I tried something like this:

```
angular.extend($scope, { defaults: { map: { scrollWheelZoom: true} } });
```

But nothing happens after I change this. Can somebody help me how to update `defaults` value?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else still comes across this:

```
$scope.defaults = {
    tileLayer: "http://{s}.tile.opencyclemap.org/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    scrollWheelZoom: false
}
```

can be passed like

```
<leaflet defaults="defaults"></leaflet>
```